# Double 'else' statement in pascal

Tags: c++, pascal

I was trying to translate the following Pascal code to C++, when I stumbled upon the "else else" construction in question. I've never seen this before, so could anybody tell me what it does and what are it's C++ (or maybe C) equivalents?

```
  Procedure Force(Q:Int64;V,K:Integer);
   Var i,j,t:Integer;
    begin
     if K<=0 then
      if (Q>=A)and(Q Mod KK =0)and(V>=S)and(V<=F)then Out:=Out+1 else else
       For i:=0 to 9 do
        if (Q+(i+1)*h[k-1]>=A)and(Q+i*h[k-1]<=B) then
         if (Q+(i+1)*h[K-1]<B)and(Q+i*h[k-1]>=A) then
          Begin
           M:=(Q+i*h[k-1]) Mod KK;
           For j:=0 to 9*(K-1) do
            For t:=0 to KK-1 do
             if D[K-1,j,t]>0 then
              if (V+i+j>=S)and(V+i+j<=F)and((t+M) Mod KK=0) then
                 Out:=Out+D[K-1,j,t];
           end else
            if Odd(N-K+1) then Force(Q+i*h[k-1],V+i,K-1) else
                               Force(Q+i*h[k-1],V+i,K-1);
    end;
```

Comment: It's an empty else statement, see the last snippet [here](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Else).

Comment: Line up each `else` with an `if` you will see there is no magic.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. I can't believe I overlooked something like that, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just copied to an editor (for instance Komodo, where you can select Pascal as language for syntax color highlighting) and reformatted the text you've wrote in a way I can read it myself.

```
procedure Force(Q:Int64;V,K:Integer);
var 
  i,j,t:Integer;
begin
  if K<=0 then
    if (Q>=A) and (Q Mod KK =0) and (V>=S) and (V<=F) then
      Out:=Out+1
    else
  else
    for i:=0 to 9 do begin
      if (Q+(i+1)*h[k-1]>=A) and (Q+i*h[k-1] <= B) then
        if (Q+(i+1)*h[K-1]<B) and (Q+i*h[k-1] >= A) then begin
          M := (Q+i*h[k-1]) Mod KK;
          for j:=0 to 9*(K-1) do begin
            for t:=0 to KK-1 do begin
              if D[K-1,j,t] > 0 then
                if (V+i+j >= S) and (V+i+j <= F) and ((t+M) mod KK = 0) then
                  Out:=Out+D[K-1,j,t];
            end; {for t}
          end; {for j}
        end else
          if Odd(N-K+1) then
            Force(Q+i*h[k-1],V+i,K-1)
          else
            Force(Q+i*h[k-1],V+i,K-1);
      end;
    end;
end;
```

Don't you think it is more understandable now?

Comment: This is correct, but I would have changed `if A then if B and C and D then` into `if A and B and C and D then`.(the two ifs that start with `if D[`).

Answer (score 1):

It's quite often useful to use `begin` and `end` pairs even when they're not required by the syntax, just to make the code more readable and understandable. (Think of `begin` being the equivalent of `{` and `end` being the equivalent of `}`; while you can write `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) SomeCode();`, it's usually more clear to use `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { SomeCode(); }`.

So the code you've posted, with `begin` and `end` pairs added where appropriate, a no-op `else` or two removed, and more appropriate formatting seems much more readable to me.

```
Procedure Force(Q: Int64; V, K: Integer);
Var
  i, j, t: Integer;
begin
  if K <= 0 then
  begin
    if (Q >= A) and (Q Mod KK = 0) and (V >= S) and (V <= F) then
      Out := Out + 1;
  end
  else
  begin
    For i := 0 to 9 do
    begin
      if (Q + (i + 1) * h[K - 1] >= A) and (Q + i * h[K - 1] <= B) then
      begin
        if (Q + (i + 1) * h[K - 1] < B) and (Q + i * h[K - 1] >= A) then
        begin
          M := (Q + i * h[K - 1]) Mod KK;
          For j := 0 to 9 * (K - 1) do
          begin
            For t := 0 to KK - 1 do
            begin
              if D[K - 1, j, t] > 0 then
              begin
                if (V + i + j >= S) and (V + i + j <= F) and
                   ((t + M) Mod KK = 0) then
                  Out := Out + D[K - 1, j, t];
              end;
            end;
          end;
        end
        else if Odd(N - K + 1) then
          Force(Q + i * h[K - 1], V + i, K - 1)
        else
          Force(Q + i * h[K - 1], V + i, K - 1);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I personally find that less readable. Too much `begin-end` noise.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: He is passing the algorithm to C++, so he will have less `begin-end` noise! XD

Comment: @I personally find the execution flow just as clear if there is not so much begin-end noise (or, in some other languages, {-} noise).

Answer (score 0):

That is some horrible indentation. If we indent it better we can see what's going on:

```
if K<=0 then
    if (Q>=A)and(Q Mod KK =0)and(V>=S)and(V<=F) then 
        Out:=Out+1 
    else 
else
   For i:=0 to 9 do
```

Here, the first else applies to the `if (Q>=A)`, but it's empty.

Comment: Each `else` matches the nearest possible `if`. I would have used `begin` and `end` to make the code clearer.

Comment: You replaced horrible indentation with even more horrible indentation!!

Comment: @sergiol: it may not be your choice, but the indentation in the original question is the worst. It does not convey the structure of the code. The indentation in this answer is pretty standard, except for the 4 spaces (or 3) which is rather C-ish.

Comment: What? An else having nothing? I don't want to learn indentation in the same schools as you all!

Comment: @sergiol: An `else` with no statement (or rather with an empty statement) is not an indentation issue. It's added here so that the *second* `else` binds to the first `if` rather than to the second one. Given that decision, the indentation is correct. (As I mentioned, an arguably better solution would be to use `begin` and `end`.)

Comment: Oh! You pointed a thing a didn't remember from the Pascal language! An empty `else` after a line without a `;` is like the termination of a "non `begin`...`end`" `if` block!

Comment: @sergiol: what Keith Thompson said. That is not an indentation issue. I even agree with Keith that here, I would use begin and end and not a double else, but that latter is valid too. For that situation, this answer shows proper indentation.